# parse xml files directly on AWS S3

Tags: xml, amazon-s3, xml-parsing, amazon-athena, amazon-kinesis

i need to parse some xml file directly on S3 Bucket

what i need to extract is:
<assemblyIdentity **name="Anthea Services"** **version="10.5.20276.322"**

and is placed always on the second line of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<asmv1:assembly xsi:schemaLocation="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1 assembly.adaptive.xsd" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:co.v1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:clickonce.v1" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:asmv1="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" xmlns:asmv2="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2" xmlns:xrml="urn:mpeg:mpeg21:2003:01-REL-R-NS" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <assemblyIdentity name="Anthea Services" version="10.5.20276.322" publicKeyToken="56904a0c05b434f1" language="it-IT" processorArchitecture="msil" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" />
```

to extract these values the files can be treated as xml or as text, simply parsing the text and search for the string (the values i need to capture are at the beginnig of the files, always at the second row,  so i can get a fraction of the file if possible) anyway,
regardless the method to extract these values **i'd like to do the job using directly some AWS services without download the files elsewhere(directly on the S3 bucket)**

I know there is the "Athena" service that allows to query files on S3 bucket in sql like language but theses file should be csv, json or parquet, the mine is xml,

another solution could be "kinesis" (making the ingestion from S3) even if my file are not created in real time but they are already in the bucket

Does exist other solutions?
Could someone suggest me a viable solution and some detailed steps to achieve it?

Comment: How about using Lambda?

Comment: @shimo of course is an a viable option! i was investigating if there are others services to use and learn